# How to implement dense x block-diagonal matrix multiplication in CUDA?

Tags: matrix, cuda, diagonal, cublas

Assume you have a dense matrix of size 1500x500 and you need to multiply it with a block-diagonal matrix of size 500x500 that consists of ten sub-matrices of size 50x50 sitting on the diagonal:

```
S 0 ... 0 0
0 S     0 0
...
0 0 ... S 0
0 0 ... 0 S  <- each S is 50x50
```

Sometimes all S are equal, sometimes they're not.

I haven't profiled yet but I feel like a straight CUBLAS multiplication would waste too much time with the zeros. Are there any efficient ways to implement such a multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [cuSparse](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#axzz46vleqYHf) with the Block Compressed Sparse Row Format as described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#block-compressed-sparse-row-format-bsr). Your matrix type may benefit from other optimizations, but this one is available now.

Alternately, you may use [cublas<>gemmBatched](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemmbatched) accessing your dense matrix by blocks of row or columns, and defining your block-diagonal as a set of smaller dense matrices (potentially reusing same data).